# Convert Large Binary String to Decimal in Java

Tags: java, binary, decimal

Need a bit of help here:

I was assigned a project to convert a Hex values in a file to Decimal using Java without using methods available in Java that can do this directly(we have to do it the long way).

I have converted my Hex values to Binary successfully but am having trouble converting the Binary strings to Decimal. The output is not correct; I only need help in this section so I just put the first binary value I need to convert to make things simple to understand and explain. Here is what I have so far

```
public class binToDec {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int decimal = 0;
        String binary = "101010111100110111101111101010111100";
        for (int pow = (binary.length()-1); pow > -1; pow--) {
            if (binary.charAt(pow)=='1'){
            decimal += (Math.pow(2, pow));
            }
        }
        System.out.print(decimal);
    }
}
```

> run: 2147483647 //this is incorrect. it should be 46118402748

Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Assignment, you can try out urself.. by the way, Java Class name is desired to be `BinToDec` and not `binToDec`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 problems with your code.

1. Overflow is certainly occurring, because an `int` can hold only a value up to 2^31 - 1, and there are more than 31 bits in your `binary` string.  Declare `decimal` to be a `long`.

   ```
   long decimal = 0;
   ```
2. You are applying the exponent from the wrong end of your loop when adding to `decimal`.  The `0` char is the most significant, but you are sending in an exponent of `0`, as if it was the least significant.  Try

   ```
   decimal += (Math.pow(2, (len - pow - 1)));
   ```

   (This assumes `len` is declared as `int len = binary.length();`.)

   Using `Math.pow` could be considered overkill.  You can also try

   ```
   decimal += 1L << (len - pow - 1);
   ```

Comment: Your answer is better than mine, but one edit: it should be "there are more than *32* bits in your `binary` string".

Comment: @Jashaszun In Java, `int`s are signed, so using that most significant 32nd bit will cause overflow (if it's set).  In fact, using `long` just puts off the problem, as this will still have an overflow problem if there are more than 63 bits represented in the `binary` string.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering and explaining! Got it to work perfectly!

Comment: @rgettman Ah right, of course! I can't believe I didn't get that by myself.

Answer (score 0):

It won't work because `int` in Java is 32-bit, and your binary string there has 36 bits. This will result in overflow.

Comment: what types can I use?

Comment: Long, because it's 64-bit.